# for direct metastore db connections we don t support retries at the client level

Tags: hive

When I launch hive from the command prompt after nevigating into hive's bin directory hive opens and I am able to create a table.

When I launch hive from the command prompt in pseudo mode without going into hive's bin directory then hive shell is opening but when I attempt to create a table then I get the following error message:

> FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:For direct MetaStore DB connections, we don't support retries at the client level.)

**Question**

How can I launch hive from the command prompt without navigating to hive's bin directory and successfully create a table.

Comment: thanks for edit suggestion.

Comment: Set your paths in .basrc file like <br/> ** export HIVE_HOME=/home/impadmin/hadoop/apache-hive-2.0.1
export PATH=$PATH:$HIVE_HOME/bin:$HIVE_HOME/lib ** <br/> You will be able to start hive from anywhere on command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Set your paths in .basrc file like 
 **export HIVE_HOME=/home/impadmin/hadoop/apache-hive-2.0.1 export PATH=$PATH:$HIVE_HOME/bin:$HIVE_HOME/lib**  
 You will be able to start hive from anywhere on command prompt.